# How do you breed a double rainbow dragon?

Tags: dragonvale

I've recently got a rainbow dragon.  I bred cactus and blue fire dragons.  How do you breed a double rainbow dragon?

Answer (score 2):

Taken from the Dragonvale wikia:

> *The Double Rainbow Dragon can be bred using any two dragons, in either order, that contain at least four different elements at the Breeding Cave/Epic Breeding Island.*

The trick to doing this is making sure all the elements of the dragons that are breeding differ from each other.

A good example is River dragon and Sonic dragon. This combination has a chance to produce a double rainbow dragon, as well as a Olympus dragon.

Also from personal experience, I've received a double rainbow dragon from breeding a Salamander dragon and a Scoria dragon.

This will most likely take some tries, as it's a pretty rare dragon!

Answer (score 0):

I bred a double rainbow dragon by breeding a rainbow dragon and another rainbow dragon. It worked after 2 days waiting for it to breed and another 2 days  and 12 hours of waiting and got a double rainbow dragon.